# Hover not working in dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, dropdown

Using glitch.com and trying to create a simple dropdown menu. 
I have used a guide and tried to make the simplest version so that I am not missing anything. However, I just cant get the hover to work for me.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 120px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul id="hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Feeling pretty defeated by this with no clear idea why its not working. 
I have messed around with the hover statement just to get it to work but to no avail.

Comment: you used `id="hidden"` => in CSS, it must be `#hidden` not `.hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css targets **ID** with # and **Class** with period .

You have hidden as an ID so you could:

Change your css to

```
ul li a:hover + #hidden, #hidden:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

or html to:

```
<ul class="hidden">
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 120px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

li ul {
  display: none;
}

li ul li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}

ul li a:hover + #hidden, #hidden:hover {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul id="hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, its always the simple things.

Comment: @user3547778 No problem! Best of luck on your coding journey!